# My phone doesn't connect to PC

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, device-manager

in the last week, I've been trying to connect my Meizu m2 phone to my computer for debugging purposes (running an app from the android studio) without any success.

I've enabled my `USB` debugging mode on my device, I've connected it to be on `MTP` rather than `PTP`, and I've also taken a look at my computer's device manager, and seen that the device wasn't listed under other devices category, and honestly I couldn't tell where was he listed.

In addition, I've opened an android studio and pressed the `run-app` button, but my phone wasn't recognized by the android studio.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: Have you installed USB driver for device?

Comment: Yes i did installed it

Comment: Which OS you used in computer?

Comment: I have used windows 10

Comment: check with `adb devices`

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Try installing PdaNet+ Windows app
   http://pdanet.co/a/
2. Install PdaNet+ Android app on your device. Download from Play Store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pdanet&hl=en
3. Now connect your phone to PC/Laptop
4. Open Android Studio and check device connected or not

Hope this will be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

There is many reasons and some instructions :

1- disable `driver signature enforcement` and connect again
2- install [Universal Driver](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver)
3- install another [ADB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html)